# Nested Array-like environment without Math-region

Tags: vertical-alignment, verbatim, arrays, nesting

I'm working on my master thesis and I need to render some structures like this:

[image: 1]

Edit: Example doesn't use highlighting for the sake of simplification, but I would like to use specifically `minted`, not just typewriter font, if possible.

Currently, I'm using `array` environment, because I need centering, brackets and nesting. However, it implies math-mode, while I need mostly verbatim, so I need to always insert `\mintinline{}{}` at each line.

```latex
\[
    \left[
    \begin{array}{l}
        \left[
        \begin{array}{l}
            \mintinline{text}{Note that} \\
            \mintinline{text}{all text} \\
            \mintinline{text}{is verbatim} \\
        \end{array}
        \right]
            \to 
        \mintinline{text}{note vertical centering} \\[2em]


        \left[
        \begin{array}{l}
            \mintinline{text}{Lorem ipsum} \\
            \mintinline{text}{dolor sit amet, consectetur} \\
        \end{array}
        \right]
            \to
        \left[
        \begin{array}{l}
            \mintinline{text}{Note that} \\
            \mintinline{text}{nested hierarchy} \\
            \mintinline{text}{can be} \\
            \mintinline{text}{quite complex} \\
        \end{array}
        \right]  \\
    \end{array}
    \right]
\]
```

Is there any way to make the code less ugly and verbose?

Also, it is not required, but it would be just wonderful if I could align each line horizontally by arrow sign.

I'm still lack experience when it comes to some advanced formatting in LaTeX, so I would greatly appreciate any help!

Comment: `tabular` shares all the code of `array` except for putting things  in math maode.

Comment: using minted is overkill (requiring an external python process) if you just want monspace fonts. For the examples you show you do not even need verbatim just `\texttt{some text}` do you need verbatim in your real document?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thank you for your answers. 
I'm sorry but I've forgot to mention that I also need some kind of braces to clearly express grouping of some lines. I will edit question to articulate it explicitly. Is there any way to achieve this in `tabular`?

Also, I use minted because I need highlighting (it is absent in example for the sake of simplification).

Comment: do you want to send each line to minted separately or is it really a multi-line code block you could send in one go?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle it is in fact multi-line code block, but I'm struggling to insert minted-environment inside a `tabular`/`array`. AFAIK, I have to use `p` tag instead of `l`, but that's inconvenient because I have to set width manually. So I have resorted to several lines of `mintinline`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}



\newcommand{\textarray}[1]{\ensuremath{\left[ \mbox{\ttfamily\begin{tabular}{l} #1 \end{tabular}}\right]}}

\begin{document}



\textarray{
\textarray{Note that \\ all text \\ is verbatim} $\rightarrow$ not vertical centering \\[4ex]
\textarray{Lorem ipsum \\ dolor sit amet, consectetur}  
}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatimbox,stackengine}
\setstackEOL{\\}
\begin{document}
\begin{myverbbox}{\UpLeft}
Note that
all text
is verbatim
\end{myverbbox}
\begin{myverbbox}{\UpRight}
note vertical centering
\end{myverbbox}
\begin{myverbbox}{\LowLeft}
Lorem ipsum
dolor sit amet, consecetur
\end{myverbbox}
\begin{myverbbox}{\LowRight}
Note that
nested hierarchy
can be
quite complex
\end{myverbbox}
\savestack\TopRow{$\bracketVectorstack{\UpLeft} \rightarrow \UpRight$}
\savestack\BottomRow{$\bracketVectorstack{\LowLeft} \rightarrow \bracketVectorstack{\LowRight}$}
\[
\renewcommand\stackalignment{l}
\left[
\stackanchor[8pt]{\TopRow}{\BottomRow}
\right]
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

If I spend the time to clean up the spacings, and align at the arrows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatimbox,tabstackengine}
\TABstackMath
\begin{document}
\begin{myverbbox}{\UpLeft}
Note that
all text
is verbatim
\end{myverbbox}
\begin{myverbbox}{\UpRight}
note vertical centering
\end{myverbbox}
\begin{myverbbox}{\LowLeft}
Lorem ipsum \#@%$^&
dolor sit amet, consecetur
\end{myverbbox}
\begin{myverbbox}{\LowRight}
Note that
nested hierarchy
can be
quite complex
\end{myverbbox}
\savestack\TopRow{$\bracketVectorstack{\UpLeft} 
  \rightarrow \UpRight$}
\savestack\BottomRow{$\bracketVectorstack{\LowLeft} 
  \rightarrow \bracketVectorstack{\addstackgap{\LowRight}}$}
\[
\renewcommand\stackalignment{l}
\left[
\raisebox{6pt}{\tabbedstackanchor[8pt]{\bracketVectorstack{\UpLeft} 
  &\rightarrow \UpRight}{\bracketVectorstack{\LowLeft} 
  &\rightarrow \bracketVectorstack{\addstackgap{\LowRight}}}}
\right]
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Less to type:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools,minted}

\newenvironment{lbmatrix}{\begin{bmatrix*}[l]}{\end{bmatrix*}}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{lbmatrix}
  \begin{lbmatrix}
    \mintinline{text}{Note that} \\
    \mintinline{text}{all text} \\
    \mintinline{text}{is verbatim}
  \end{lbmatrix}
  \rightarrow
  \mintinline{text}{note vertical centering}
\\[2ex]
  \begin{lbmatrix}
    \mintinline{text}{Lorem ipsum} \\
    \mintinline{text}{dolor sit amet, consectetur}
  \end{lbmatrix}
  \rightarrow
  \begin{lbmatrix}
    \mintinline{text}{Note that} \\
    \mintinline{text}{nested hierarchy} \\
    \mintinline{text}{can be} \\
    \mintinline{text}{quite complex}
  \end{lbmatrix}
\end{lbmatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]